# how fix android Setters that changes similar array list values?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i have a Arraylist with Getters and Setters:

```
public class TestList {

    String name ;
    Double val ;

    public TestList(String name, Double val) {
        this.name = name;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Double getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setVal(Double val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

i added some data to arraylist :

```
List<TestList> testList = new ArrayList<>();

TestList listA= new TestList("BBBB",28.0);
TestList listB= new TestList("ABCD",22.0);

testList.add(listA);
testList.add(listB);
testList.add(listB);
testList.add(listB);
testList.add(listB);
```

Then i use setter to change some value of array list , then i got a problem :

```
testList.get(2).setName("WWWW");
testList.get(3).setVal(44.5);
```

Out Put of above arraylist [name : val]:

```
BBBB : 28.0

WWWW : 44.5

WWWW : 44.5

WWWW : 44.5

WWWW : 44.5
```

i want this output,not the above one :

```
BBBB : 28.0

ABCD : 22.0

WWWW : 22.0

ABCD : 44.5

ABCD : 22.0
```

how can i fix this. i only need to change arraylist's index 2th name to "WWW" and arralist's index 3rd val to 44.5 [but here similar values are replaced] [i am using android studio]

---

fixed :
Added a cunstructor to TestList

```
public TestList(TestList other) {
        this.name = other.name;
        this.val = other.val;
    }
```

and this to method :

```
testList.add(new TestList(listB));
```

Comment: *i only need to change arraylist's index 2th name to "WWW"* that 2nd index is actually `index1`, 3rd `val` i.e 22.0 is `index` 2

Comment: You need to put new objects into the list each time, not the same objects over and over.

Comment: i am trying to set testList.get(2).getName ='www' but all the similar names are changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to this comment:

> how can i pass the object like this : new TestList(listA). (when the object have more variable it's hard to initialise every one)

You could add a constructor to your class that creates a copy:

```
public TestList(TestList other) {
    this.name = other.name;
    this.val = other.val;
}
```

Then you can create copies like this:

```
TestList original = new TestList("A", 1.0);
TestList copy1 = new TestList(original);
TestList copy2 = new TestList(original);
TestList copy3 = new TestList(original);
```

Now you will have four different references, pointing to four different objects, each with the same values.

Or you could add a method to your class:

```
public TestList createCopy() {
    return new TestList(name, val);
}
```

And then you'd create copies like this:

```
TestList original = new TestList("A", 1.0);
TestList copy1 = original.createCopy();
TestList copy2 = original.createCopy();
TestList copy3 = original.createCopy();
```

Comment: thanks      : public TestList(TestList other) {
        this.name = other.name;
        this.val = other.val;
    }   testList.add(new TestList(listB));

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a common error: you are adding the `reference` to an object to the list multiple times. When you do:

```
 testList.add(listA);
 testList.add(listB);
 testList.add(listB);
 testList.add(listB);
 testList.add(listB);
```

you add the same object 4 times to the list. The list will then contain 4 links to the same object, so when you edit `listB`, you will see the changes in all `listB` entries in the `listList`.

If you want independent objects, you should do something like this:

```
 testList.add(new TestList("BBBB",28.0));
 testList.add(new TestList("ABCD",22.0));
 testList.add(new TestList("ABCD",22.0));
 testList.add(new TestList("ABCD",22.0));
 testList.add(new TestList("ABCD",22.0));
```

Using `new` operator multiple times will create multiple, independent, objects.
You may also do something like:

```
testList.add(new TestList("BBBB",28.0));
for(int i = 0: i < 4; i++) testList.add(new TestList("ABCD",22.0));
```

in order to have a cleaner code. Hope it helps!

Comment: how can i pass the object like this :  new TestList(listA). (when the object have more variable it's hard to initialise every one)